# How to retrieve data from phpmyadmin in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have used `database -> reverse engineer` to retrieve the schema from phpmyadmin. But when I tried it, the data records that filled in table do not appear in mysql workbench. The things that appear is only the relation and the structure/attribute of the tables. What should I do so that the data records can be retrieve from phpmyadmin? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting the database in .sql

Select Database > Export > SQL > Go

Answer (score 0):

You probably tried to reverse engineer the script in the modeling section, which creates a model from the content. A model doesn't work with the actual data, but only the meta data (schema objects and structure).

If you actually want to import the full dump into your server then open an SQL connection to it from the homescreen and execute the script there.